# How do I increase the size of the status bar on visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, statusbar

The status bar shown on the bottom of VSCode is too small as it's hard for me to read vim commands that I'll be typing on there. I don't want to increase the font size of the editor nor the zoom since they're big enough for me.

**Basically**, I want to increase the size (font, icon, bar size, etc.) of the bottom status bar without changing the size of any other component of VSCode.

Is there a way to do that or an extension I can use to change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is no setting to adjust the height of the status bar.

A common practice is to set the zoom level and decrease the editor and terminal font size, but this will also increase the activity bar icons and other areas.

In your **settings.json** add

```json
{
  ...
  "window.zoomLevel": 0.5,
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  ...
}
```

Adjust `zoomLevel` to your liking, by default is `0`

You should increment the value by the decimal, e.g. `0.1`, `0.15` ...

Or in your **Settings** `Cmd + ,` search for `window zoom level` and change the value there.

Comment: As of right now that sounds about the only solution to the problem (I'll update this if Microsoft ever makes a update) so thank you for your incite and detailed answer kind sir!